# VueJS - Conditionally wrap inside a div

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a v-for loop on VueJS and I want to wrap the loop elements inside a div in groups of two.

For example:

```
<div class="xpto" v-for="item in items"> //this div should wrap a maximum of two components per time
  <component :item="item"></component>
</div>
```

What would be the best way to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by referencing the index of each item and getting the item from the `items` array at the calculated index:

```
<div 
  class="xpto" 
  v-for="n, i in items.length" 
  v-if="i < items.length / 2"
>
  <component 
    v-for="m, j in 2" 
    v-if="items[i*2+j]" 
    :item="items[i*2+j]"
  ></component>
</div>
```

Comment: Some day someone is going to mess with the order of the attributes or rename the wrong thing and you are going to have a lot of trouble. whenever a v-if goes with a v-for, there is a computed that begs to be created. See Bert's answer

Comment: @felipeecst yeah, I agree with Romain that Bert's suggestion to use a computed property would be the more appropriate handling of this type of problem in most cases. I do think it is helpful for people to know that tags with `v-for` can also be conditionally rendered with `v-if`, but I think Bert's answer should be the accepted one.

Answer (score 3):

This seems like something you would really want to do in a computed. I can look at the name of the computed and have a pretty good idea of what it's doing.

```
computed:{
  itemPairs(){
     let p = [], copy = [...this.items]
     while(copy.length > 0)
       p.push(copy.splice(0, 2))
    return p
  }
}
```

Template

```
<div v-for="pair in itemPairs" :key="pair" class="xpto">
  <component v-for="item in pair" 
            :item="item" 
            :key="item">
  </component>
</div>
```

[Example](https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/Emwrox).

Answer (score 1):

You can use range v-for

```
<div class="xpto" v-for="n in 2"> //this div should wrap a 
    maximum of two components per time
  <component :item="items[n-1]"></component>
</div>
```

Vue.js Docs: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Range-v-for